# Can I install a humidifier on a horizontal duct?

Tags: hvac, humidifier

I have a Honeywell whole-house humidifier (HE360A1075). Can this be installed on the horizontal ducting here on the left? It feels like it's an aluminum box under the tape.

This is both gas heat and AC, over the winter heat only.

I can run water and drainage from the floor below, as there's a bathroom almost under this attic space. The space itself is insulated, so temp shouldn't be an issue.

My primary concern is whether this part of the ducting is sufficient to actually install on.

Secondary question - the AC drains out of the side of the house, from the drain piping seen here. Is it safe to drain out here? I assume not, as it would probably freeze over winter, something which wouldn't happen with AC as it only runs during the summer.

[image: Attic HVAC]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's plenty of space to install a humidifier, provided it's air intake scoop is designed to operate or can be installed horizontally. Freezing of the supply line or its drain is a concern; steam humidifiers are recommended for unconditioned spaces. Drain it inside, install a catch pan and a shut-off switch, like you have for your AC coil. Sharing that installed pan's drain and safety switch will not help; it only shuts down the AC condenser, not the entire furnace.